# Can we get out of transit airport after immigration is complete at the port of entry airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, airport-security

I am traveling from USA to Ahmedabad via Mumbai. I have a layover of 6 hrs in Mumbai. Can I go out of airport after my immigration is done in Mumbai?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mumbai - Ahmedabad is a domestic flight and so you will do entry checks in Mumbai. And, apart from time at the transit point, nothing prevents you to leave the airport after passing immigration flight

You can just exit the secure area after you passed entry checks and re-enter for your flights, make sure to have enough time to do it though

Comment: This is correct, however they shouldn’t overestimate the actual free time available between immigration and re-entry security checks (assuming they don’t *also* have to re-check their bags). Add traffic to the mix and I’d say they have about **one** safe hour outside the airport.